# Duda sobre múltiples selects y updates ejecutados al mismo tiempo

Tags: php, mysqli

El problema es el siguiente:

Supongamos que 10.000 personas ven al mismo tiempo 1 video el cual contabiliza las visualizaciones realizadas al mismo, 100 de estas personas lo visualizaron en el mismo instante de manera que al actualizar sucede que al realizar la consulta a la base de datos se obtiene (por ejemplo):

```
VIEWS=60.000
VIEWS+=1
UPDATE = 60,001
```

Si la consulta inicial (60.000) se realiza al mismo instante se estaría perdiendo la contabilización de las otras 99 personas que visualizaron el video ya que se registraría 60.001 (debería ser 60.100 de allí la diferencia de 99 personas)

**1**-Las transacciones solucionarían esto?

```
($conn->autocommit(false);  , 
$conn->commit; , $conn->rollback;)
```

**2**- Estoy ejecutando un bucle para ello, realmente debe ser de esta forma? Lo pregunto por la duda que tengo en si este bucle afectaría mucho el "rendimiento" del sistema.

El proceso realizado por el bucle es que si al verificar si los cambios no son lo esperado (60.001 como resultado cuando debe ser 60.100) entonces repite el proceso hasta lograr la salida esperada.

**3**-Son 2 tablas las que se modifican (1 Visualizaciones totales y 2 visualizacion de foto o video) podría realizar un proceso más complejo?

```
        $conn->autocommit(false); 
        $twist=0;
        while ($twist<10){
            $query = $conn->query("select views from posts where id = '" . $post_id_video . "';");
            $fetch = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
            $query=$fetch['views'];
            $query+=1;
            $postq1=$query;

            $conn->query("UPDATE posts SET views=".$query." WHERE id=" . $post_id_video);



            $data['html']=$query;



        /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


        if ($a=="ismovile"){

            if ($sell==0){
                $query = $conn->query("select fotoviewsmov from accounts where id = '" . $video_views_id . "';");
                $fetch = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                $query=$fetch['fotoviewsmov'];
                $query+=1;
                $cou_acco1=$query;

                $conn->query("UPDATE accounts SET fotoviewsmov=".$query." WHERE id=" . $video_views_id);



                //watphomov($user["id"],$conn);
            }
        }
        $query = $conn->query("select fotoviewsmov from accounts where id = '" . $video_views_id . "';");
        $fetch = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $query=$fetch['fotoviewsmov'];
        $cou_acco2=$query;

        $query = $conn->query("select views from posts where id = '" . $post_id_video . "';");
        $fetch = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        $query=$fetch['views'];
        $postq2=$query;

        if($cou_acco2==$cou_acco1 and $postq1==$postq2){

            $conn->commit; 
            $twist=10;

        }else{
        $conn->rollback;
        $twist+=1;
        }

    }
```

Gracias!!

Comment: La publicación es difícil de leer y de entender (muchas partes no terminan de tener sentido). Por favor, edita tu pregunta para clarificar el problema y no pongas todo el texto en mayúsculas (que en Internet son el equivalente a gritar). Lee [ask] para más información y comentarios y completa el [tour] para ver cómo funciona el sitio en general.

Comment: Todo este problema se solucionaría haciendo un UPDATE valor=valor+1 directamente en la base de datos, en lugar de hacer los cambios en el servidor de la manera en la que se están haciendo. Es un problema causado por un mal diseño del software.

Comment: No encuentro algo que editarle , la pregunta en concreto es:

¿ Es posible que la base de datos haga 2 consultas  (select) al mismo tiempo para despues ejecutar los 2 update correspondientes??

Ambas obtienen el mismo numero 

60,000

y ambas actualizan con 60,001

si son 2 , al final deberia quedar 60,002 , pero como inicialmente ambas obtuvieron 60,000 , al final se pierde 1 visualizacion.

Es posible que eso ocurra...?

Comment: Ok , encontre esto:

http://qualisys.com.co/articulo-mysql-manejo-concurrencia-lock-tables

Que es precisamente lo que necesitaba , por favor podrian comentarme que tan costoso seria para la base de datos ejecutar tal cosa...?

Es recomendable en ese sentido..?(el costo de ejecucion/red)

Comment: Como indica @AlvaroMontoro el problema de concurrencia para este caso se esta dando debido al un mal diseño de la del código, deberias delegar completamente el incremento en 1 de `views` directamente a MySQL no en PHP, de esta manera será indiferente en el orden que se ejecuten las consultas, aparte de tener un codigo mas limpio.

Answer (score 1):

Las bases de datos tienen sistemas para evitar el problema de la concurrencia (que varias operaciones o usuarios accedan a los mismos datos al mismo tiempo) de manera que no se pierdan datos.

Por ejemplo, hay una seria de operaciones que, debido a que cambian los datos de una tabla, bloquean (*lock*) dicha tabla o la fila que se está modificando para evitar que otra operación interactúe con los datos mientras están siendo cambiados.

Entonces, realmente el problema que presentas no tiene que ver con que muchos usuarios accedan a tu sitio al mismo tiempo o que muchas actualizaciones se ejecuten al mismo tiempo, es un problema con el diseño del software. Es un problema por cómo se están actualizando los datos.

Éste es tu código:

```
$query = $conn->query("select fotoviewsmov from accounts where id = '" . $video_views_id . "';");
$fetch = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$query=$fetch['fotoviewsmov'];
$query+=1;
$cou_acco1=$query;

$conn->query("UPDATE accounts SET fotoviewsmov=".$query." WHERE id=" . $video_views_id);
```

Lo que se está haciendo ahora es (todo desde PHP):

1. Leer la base de datos para obtener el número de vistas
2. Incrementar la variable con el número de vistas agregando 1
3. Actualizar la base de datos para guardar el nuevo valor de las vistas

Y el **problema** reside en que ese incremento (punto 2) lo estás realizando en PHP sin tener en cuenta que durante ese tiempo puede haber más vistas que estén afectando al número existente. Por lo que estarías actualizando el valor a un número que ya no es cierto.

La **solución** sería delegar el cambio a la base de datos. Puedes seguir leyendo las vistas por si necesitas realizar operaciones con ellas, pero sería ideal que juntases los pasos 2 y 3 en uno solo. De ese modo lo que harías sería incrementar el valor actual de las vistas en la base de datos en lugar de con el valor que venga desde PHP. Algo como esto:

> **OJO: este código contiene sentencias SQL dinámicas y, dependiendo de los valores y su origen, puede ser vulnerable a ataques de inyección SQL. Deberías usar sentencias preparadas/parametrizadas para evitar problemas.**

```
$query = $conn->query("select fotoviewsmov from accounts where id = '" . $video_views_id . "';");
$fetch = $query->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$query=$fetch['fotoviewsmov'];
$cou_acco1=$query;

$conn->query("UPDATE accounts SET fotoviewsmov=fotoviewsmov+1 WHERE id=" . $video_views_id);
```

Sólo he cambiado una cosa, ahora el `update` es así:

```
UPDATE accounts SET fotoviewsmov=fotoviewsmov+1 WHERE id=" . $video_views_id
```

haciendo eso, el valor que se va a actualizar es el presente en la base de datos y no el que leíste/procesaste en PHP. De ese modo si hubiera 100 o 1.000 vistas al mismo tiempo, el valor en la base de datos se actualizaría 100 o 1.000 veces con +1. Sin necesidad de usar transacciones o herramientas externas.

Comment: Gracias Alvaro =)